# arranging an array of different groups so that it's elements have no neighbours from similar group

Tags: php, arrays, graph-coloring

I have an array that can be separated into 3 different groups by one of it's attributes:

```
$shuffleMeGood = array(
    0 => array('id' => '1', 'group' => 'banana'),
    1 => array('id' => '2', 'group' => 'banana'),
    2 => array('id' => '3', 'group' => 'banana'),
    3 => array('id' => '4', 'group' => 'airplane'),
    4 => array('id' => '5', 'group' => 'coconut'),
    5 => array('id' => '6', 'group' => 'coconut')
    ...
);
```

The size of groups can vary, there could be 7 coconut elements and 5 airplane elements and so on. How can I shuffle the array in a way that there are no or the least possible occurrences of neighbors of the same group?

I tried to part them into 3 different arrays and merge them again pairwise by a ratio based on their size. But with groups that have a ratio near ,5 I end up having a block of one group at the end.

Comment: That isn't PHP, that's JSON.

Comment: Isn't this a variant of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Adapted the answer according to OP's comments on how he wants to handle the remaining items. Keeping my original answer below.

We'll distribute the largest group evenly in each other by calculating how many we can put in each and using some intermediate arrays:

```
<?php
// Your array changed to PHP with some added items
$a = array(
    array(
        'id'=>1,
        'group'=>'banana'
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>2,
        'group'=>'banana'
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>3,
        'group'=>'banana'
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>4,
        'group'=>'airplane'
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>5,
        'group'=>'coconut'
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>6,
        'group'=>'coconut'
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>7,
        'group'=>'coconut'
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>8,
        'group'=>'coconut'
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>9,
        'group'=>'coconut'
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>10,
        'group'=>'coconut'
    ),
);

// We want to know each of group there are
// We also want to arrange the items in a new "perGroup" array.
$counts = array();
$perGroup = array();
foreach($a as $key=>$value){
    // Avoid PHP undefined notices
    if(isset($counts[$value['group']])){
        $counts[$value['group']]++;

    }else{
        $counts[$value['group']] = 1;
    }

    // Avoid PHP undefined notices
    if(isset($perGroup[$value['group']])){
        $perGroup[$value['group']][] = $value;
    }else{
        $perGroup[$value['group']] = array();
        $perGroup[$value['group']][] = $value;
    }
}

// Sort the count from largest to lowest
arsort($counts);
// Get all the group names
$keys = array_keys($counts);
// We'll have as many unique groups as the SECOND largest item.
$nbOfUniques = $counts[$keys[1]];
// Calculate how many of the largest we need to put in each unique
$nbOfLargestPerUnique = ceil($counts[$keys[0]] / $nbOfUniques);
// Get the largest group name for easier use
$largestGroupName = $keys[0];

$finalArray = array();
// Loop for how many unique groups we have
for ($i = 1; $i <= $nbOfUniques; $i++) {
    // For each group...
    foreach($keys as $k=>$v){
        // If its the largest
        if($v == $largestGroupName){
            // Add as many as needed
            for ($j = 1; $j <= $nbOfLargestPerUnique; $j++) {
                // Make sure we actually have an item, as the number is not always exact.
                // Using array_shift() to reduce our array
                if(($item = array_shift($perGroup[$v])) !== NULL){
                    $finalArray[] = $item;
                }
            }
        }else{
            // Not the largest group, just add one
            if(($item = array_shift($perGroup[$v])) !== NULL){
                $finalArray[] = $item;
            }
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($finalArray);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

**ORIGINAL:** 
I'd use a recursive function with two arrays: the final one, and a copy of the initial one that gets smaller and smaller until we processed all of it:

```
<?php
// Your array changed to PHP with some added items
$a = array(
    array(
        'id'=>1,
        'group'=>'banana'
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>2,
        'group'=>'banana'
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>3,
        'group'=>'banana'
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>4,
        'group'=>'airplane'
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>5,
        'group'=>'coconut'
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>6,
        'group'=>'coconut'
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>7,
        'group'=>'coconut'
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>8,
        'group'=>'coconut'
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>9,
        'group'=>'coconut'
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>10,
        'group'=>'coconut'
    ),
);

// Our recursive function
// $array is the array to be ordered (in our case, $a)
// $orderedArray is needed for the recusivity part
function orderArray($array, $orderedArray = array()){
    // Remember the last processed group
    $lastGroup = '';

    // Loop on all $array's items
    foreach($array as $key=>$value){
        // If NOT the same as the last group
        if($value['group'] != $lastGroup){
            // Add it to our orderedArray
            $orderedArray[] = $value;
            // Remember its group
            $lastGroup = $value['group'];
            // Remove it from the original array, as it has already been processed
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }
    // There are still items to be processed
    if(count($array) > 0){
        // Call ourselves again, with the same arrays
        return orderArray($array, $orderedArray);
    }else{
        // Done processing, return the $orderedArray
        return $orderedArray;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump(orderArray($a));
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

However, if one group clearly outnumbers the others (like coconut in my example), you will end up with a bunch of coconuts at the end.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thank you, but then it's gonna be almost the same outcome as in my version. As I stated I also ended up with a block of one group at the end..

Comment: Well there's really no way to avoid it if you have one group that outnumbers the others. What do you want to do with the additional items ?

Comment: They should be distributed evenly throughout the array. Instead of:

coconut - airplane - banana - coconut - banana - coconut - banana - coconut - coconut - coconut

... It should result in:

coconut - airplane - coconut - banana - coconut - coconut - banana coconut - coconut - banana

Comment: Added a new version now that you said what you expected.. My first answer wasn't worth a downvote, by the way.

Comment: Hey, maybe you should just do it on your own, @Kana instead of telling other people what your specs are and getting them to do it.

Comment: I didn't downvote anything and I didn't say someone else should program it for me either (They did this on their own, free will, it seems). I merely asked what would be a good way to do it.

Comment: What's with all the downvoting now? Now my question gets a downvote? I don't think its that dumb of a question. Stackoverflow has become such a hateful place.. ;_;

Comment: I didn't downvote anything either. Can you please review my latest edit and mark it as resolved if it does resolve ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think it is resolved. If the array has 4x banana, 3x airplane and 6x coconut, the result will have pairs of 2x coconuts. Even though it would be possible by their numbers that not any of them have same neighbors. There must be a more plausible solution to this. I tried to apply greedy coloring from Tibrogargan's answer to this problem, but I'm stuck how to implement it.